# AngularJS .component() API is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a component "claList" using .component() API. But its not working.
(I am using AngularJS 1.5 version.) Below is the code that I have written.

```
//state configuration
$stateProvider
    .state("abc", {
        url: "/abc",
        templateUrl: "/index.html",
        abstract: true
    })
     .state("abc.state1", {
        url: "/state1",
        template: "<cla-list></cla-list>"
    });


//JS Code
var app = angular.module("app");
app.component("claList", { //this is not working
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "state1.html",
    controller: state1Controller
});

/*@ngInject*/
function state1Controller($scope, $timeout) {
    ....
});

//HTML code(state1.html)
<div class="list-container">
   <h2 class="text-blue">Header</h2>
   ....
</div>
```

It is also not displaying any error in the console.

Comment: Is the router navigating correctly to your `abc.state1` route?

Comment: @Brad yes.Its working

Comment: Have you tried using `directive("claList", {...});` instead?

Comment: @Brad: Yes, that is working fine. But I want to use component() API so that it will be easy to convert application when moving to AngularJS 2.0

Answer (score -1):

Are you using ui-router? I'm stating the obvious here, but did you put  inside index.html?

Also, you don't need the restrict: 'E' in components.